# Construct new event loop on gevent workers

Tags: python, python-asyncio, gunicorn, gevent

I'm trying to run `flask` server by `gunicorn` with `gevent` workers. But my some logics use `asyncio`'s event loop. I created a new thread and ran a newly created `asyncio` event loop on that thread. But I've encountered an error saying the event loop is already running. The belows are what I met.

```
$ gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:9090 -e FLASK_ENV=dev main:app --workers 4 -k gevent
```

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self): 
        self._loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self._loop.run_forever, daemon=True)
        self._thread.start()
```

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.17/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.17/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.17/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 560, in run_forever
    self._check_running()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.17/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 554, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
```

#### Question

Q. It based on gevent worker, but why does asyncio's event loop say it's already running?

#### hypothesis

1. Gevent is based on `asyncio`. So there are some conflicts.
2. Gevent monkey-patch some logics of `asyncio` at runtime.
3. gunicorn do not run normaly.

Comment: `asyncio` block I/O when running, It conflict with gunicorn gevent are also blocked. If you use asynIO in your app, gunicorn would be run mode `gthead`